# PHP + SQLite no such column when the column exists

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm currently trying to create a script using PHP to update a couple of SQLite tables. I have the following function, that given a particular city, searches the country and updates it in the target table.

```
function fillCountry($city, $db) {                                                                                                                         

    $statement = $db->prepare('SELECT country, iso3 FROM cities WHERE city= :city;');                                                                  
    $statement->bindValue(':city', $city);                                                                                                             

    $result = $statement->execute();                                                                                                                   
    $resx = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);                                                                                                        

    if(!empty($resx['country'])){                                                                                                                      
            $db->exec('UPDATE wikivoyage_listings SET country = "' . $resx['country'] . '" WHERE article = "' . $city . '";');                         
            $db->exec('UPDATE wikivoyage_listings SET iso3 =  "' . $resx['iso3'] . '" WHERE article = "' . $city . '";');                              
    } else {                                                                                                                                           
            echo "Not Good";                                                                                                                           
    }
```

}

When running this code I get the following warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  SQLite3::exec(): no such column: country in /vagrant/connect.php on line 23                                            
PHP Warning:  SQLite3::exec(): no such column: iso3 in /vagrant/connect.php on line 24
```

The wikivoyage_listings table has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE wikivoyage_listings (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(128), language VARCHAR(2), article VARCHAR(128), type VARCHAR(64), wikidata VARCHAR (64), wikipedia VARCHAR(64), description VARCHAR(4096), latitude DECIMAL(10, 8), longitude DECIMAL(11, 8), country VARCHAR, iso3 VARCHAR);
```

The columns exist in the table but somehow they are being taken into consideration?

Any idea on why this might be happening? Any additional information I can add?

Comment: Side note: Are you sure your db design is correct? I'm asking this because "countries" shouldn't be in "cities"

Comment: @B001ᛦ I'm migrating the data in citites to the listings table. The idea is to fill the countries because I only have city information in the listings.

Comment: Ah ...got it thx - Back to your question: Does the query fail as well when you run it manually?

Comment: Yes, it works when I run the query directly on sqlite.

Comment: You actually don't need 2 separate queries here, just one update on 2 columns would be fine - have you tried this?

Comment: I haven't, but if they don't work by themselves why should they work together?

Comment: Can you show the definition of the table wikivoyage_listings

Comment: CREATE TABLE wikivoyage_listings (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(128), language VARCHAR(2), article VARCHAR(128), type VARCHAR(64), wikidata VARCHAR (64), wikipedia VARCHAR(64), description VARCHAR(4096), latitude DECIMAL(10, 8), longitude DECIMAL(11, 8), country VARCHAR, iso3 VARCHAR);

Comment: Are you sure the database your script is using is the same file you're checking by hand?

Comment: I double checked it, it is the same ;)

Comment: Have you found the solution?